# PHP: Why is my PDO select not working?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm learning PDO. Why is the below not working?  Where is my mistake / error?
I just want the query to retrieve the highest number from seconds column
..................................................

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR']) {
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR'];
} else {
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$user = "open";
$password = "r23sSF32";
$database_name = "open2";
$hostname = "localhost";

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=' . $database_name . ';host=' . $hostname;

$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

$sql = "SELECT MAX( seconds ) AS seconds FROM `opentill` WHERE ipaddress='$ipaddress'";
$conn->query($sql) as $row 

$largests = $row['seconds'];
```

Comment: `$ipaddress` is undefined? `$conn->query($sql) as $row ` is also invalid syntax. Use error reporting.

Comment: I had $ipaddress defined just did not add it in the code above, now it is there. What do I put in place of $conn->query($sql) as $row ?

Comment: This looks like it's going to be an *edit on the fly* question. This `$conn->query($sql) as $row` is incomplete; it's missing a `foreach`.

Comment: I just want the query to retrieve the highest number from seconds column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using prepared statements instead. Here's an example (untested):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT MAX( seconds ) AS seconds FROM `opentill` WHERE ipaddress = :ipaddress");
$stmt->bindParam(":ipaddress", $ipaddress); // Note: bindParam binds to the REFERENCE of the variable passed, only evaluated when execute() is called
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

`$result` now contains that column value.

Comment: that worked, thanks